# How to implement in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, testing

I need to implement in-app purchases.

1. Can I test my test app without submitting to App Store?
2. How can I create a iTunes test account for in-app purchases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can test during development without using the production version of the iTunes App Store.  The transactions are simulated and use test iTunes accounts.  See [Testing a Store](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html) for details.
2. See p. 62 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf).
   .